# Google Drive API: How can I support a large number of authorized origins?

Tags: javascript, html, google-api, google-drive-api

I am developing a feature on my website that will allow users to upload a server side document to their Google Drive account.

The issue I have is that when I create a **client ID** for the authentication I need to specify one or more **Authorized JavaScript origins** with fairly strict requirements.

This feature needs to service many different websites (around 5000 with new sites frequently being added) which have base URL structures that are similar but not the same (ex: https://site1.mydomain.com & https://site2.mydomain.com).

According to Google's in-page documentation when creating the client ID wildcards are not supported:

> For use with requests from a browser. This is the origin URI of the
>   client application. It can't contain a wildcard (http://*.example.com)
>   or a path (http://example.com/subdir). If you're using a nonstandard
>   port, you must include it in the origin URI.

Is there some way that I can get around this restriction without having to maintain thousands of URLs manually?

Comment: Have you tried authorizing 'mydomain' only by omitting the subdomains (site1, site2,etc)? If that doesnt work then Im afraid you have to manually input all of the URLs.

Comment: I have not tried this. I'll test that out and post an update. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I have confirmed that omitting the subdomain does not work. I get an *origin_mismatch* error. It appears that the only way to make this work is to manually enter every permutation of the url.